# Which version of percona db package should I install?

Tags: 11.04, mysql

I am new to both percona & Ubuntu. According to this [page](http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.1/Percona-Server-5.1.55-12.6/deb/) percona is only available for

- etch
- hardy
- lenny
- lucid
- maverick
- squeeze

But i am using 11.04 (Natty). Can someone recommend me which version should i choose?

Cheers

Comment: and which for 11.10 oneiric?

Answer (score 1):

Come across found a few references to using the maverick installation without any trouble

I just tried installing -  went in without a hitch though I've yet to have enough timeto full test

running 11.04